# Checking for swipe of object in 3d space

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm writing a game just now in Unity.  The basic premise is there are a few objects on screen in 3d space which you swipe to destroy.  I've done most of the hard graft but got stuck on something I think should be fairly simple.

I've written a touch controller which spits out the start, end and direction of a swipe.  How can I use this to check whether the swipe line in screen coordinates intersects an object in 3d space?  I've looked into Rays but can't seem to get it working when casting from anywhere but the camera.  My objects do have a collider and I attempted (briefly) to use the collider bounds too.  Just can't seem to crack it!

Any help is appreciated,

Comment: Show us some code of what you've tried. Physics.Raycast should work if you've done it correctly.

Comment: Can't at the moment - I'm at work.  I've tried casting from the start of my input line to the end using screen to world coordinates and the depth value from the object I'm checking but not with any success. I'll edit the question when I get home, if nobody can shed any light on it without examples of what I've tried.

Comment: What exactly was the problem with this approach? Does the object you're trying to raycast to has collider component?

Comment: Yeah the target object (a cube for testing) has a box collider.  I simply couldn't get it to register any hits at all using the method above.  Am I right in saying that this 'should' work (checking a ray from the start to end position, using the Z depth of the object?)

Comment: Make sure you fully understand how the layermask property works in the Raycast function.

Answer (score 0):

use "Camera.ViewportPointToRay" to shoot rays depending on which pixels are swiped. Bottom-left of the screen is (0,0) top-right is (1,1).